# Linkedlist InsertInOrder method

Tags: java

This one our first class `AbstractLinkedList<T>`

```
public abstract class AbstractLinkedList<T> {
    public class Node<T> {
        public T value;
        Node<T> next;

        public Node(T value, Node<T> next) {
            this.value = value;
            this.next = next;
        }
    }
    Node<T> head;

    public Node<T> getHead() {
        return head;
    }
    public void addFirst(T value) {
        head = new Node<>(value, head);
    }
    public void addLast(T value){
        if(head==null)
            head = new Node<>(value, null);
        else {
            Node<T> node = head;
            while (node.next!=null)
                node = node.next;
            node.next = new Node<>(value, null);
        }

    }
    public void print(){
        System.out.println(toString());
    }
    @Override
    public String toString(){
        if(head==null) return "boş";
        String r="";
        Node<T> node=head;
        while(node!=null) {
            r += node.value + (node.next!=null?" ":"");
            node=node.next;
        }
        return r;
    }

    public abstract void insertInOrder(T value);
    public abstract AbstractLinkedList<T> reverse();
    public abstract AbstractLinkedList<T> concatenate(AbstractLinkedList<T> list);
}
```

This is second one `Odev1LinkedList` implements `Comparable<T>> extends AbstractLinkedList<T>`

```
public class Odev1LinkedList<T extends Comparable<T>> extends AbstractLinkedList<T> {

    @Override
    public AbstractLinkedList<T> reverse() {

        Odev1LinkedList a = new Odev1LinkedList();
        Node<T> root = new Node(this, head);
        Node<T> iter = root;
        Node<T> temp ;
        a.head = null;

        do {            


        temp = iter;

        a.addFirst(temp.value);


        iter = iter.next;


        }while (temp !=root );

        return a;
    }
```

When I run this code  `example.reverse` should make reverse and return LinkedList without changing ORIGINAL LinkedList.
But its return without reversing

Comment: Does your JDK support generics?

Comment: `head.value.compareTo(value) < 0` instead of `head.value < value`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use the `<` operator on arbitrary objects. It's only defined for primitive numbers. Take a look into the [specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.20.1).

If your object of type `T` implements [`Comparable<T>`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Comparable.html) you can use `head.value.compareTo(value) < 0`.

If you want your objects of type `T` to implement `Comparable<T>` you have to go to your class declaration and write

```
public class MyLinkedList<T extends Comparable<T>> { ... }
```

Comment: we can't implements Comparable<T> this is homework and teach wants we do compare

Comment: @Orbay How is order defined then for objects of type `T`? What does it mean for one `T` to be less than another?

Comment: We given 2 classes first one is I will edit my ask you can see there. We imlement second one.

Comment: Which one do you have to implement? `Odev1LinkedList`?

Comment: We implement `AbstractLinkedList<T>`

Comment: If you can't change `Odev1LinkedList` then this is a bug and you should speak to your professor because as I already mentioned, comparing objects using `<` is not possible.

Comment: Sorry my bad we already implement `Comparable<T>` in `Odev1LinkedList` how we will use that?

Comment: Change `head.value<value` to `head.value.compareTo(value) < 0` as described in my answer. :)

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException
at Odev1LinkedList.insertInOrder(Odev1LinkedList.java:18)
at Odev1Tester$1.run(Odev1Tester.java:16)
at VPLTester.doTests(VPLTester.java:85)
at Odev1Tester.main(Odev1Tester.java:114   This errors shown